# Prove that $5^n \equiv 8n^2-4n+1 \mod 64$ using induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

I am trying to prove that $5^n \equiv 8n^2-4n+1 \mod 64 $ using induction. I have seen the post which solves this problem using other methods, but I really need to be able to do it using induction.

Here is what I have so far:

Base step:
$5 \equiv 5 \mod 64$

Then, I assumed that $5^k \equiv 8k^2 -4k+1 \mod 64.$

I want to prove that $5^{k+1} \equiv 8(k+1)^2-4(k+1)+1 \mod 64$.

Note that $8(k+1)^2-4(k+1)+1=8k^2+12k+5$.

Hence,
$5^{k+1} \equiv 5^k *5 \mod 64
\equiv (8k^2-4k+1)*5 \mod 64 \equiv 40k^2 -20k+5 \mod 64.$

I am stuck here.
Any insight would be very useful!!
Thanks

Comment: What is the difference between your last line and your second last line? $40k^2-20k+5-(8k^2+12k+5)$ This is $32k^2-32k$. Now can you finish it off?

Comment: But it is not mod 32... its mod 64...

Comment: What can you say about the parity of $k(k-1)$?

Comment: You are right!!! It is even! Thus, 32*2=64.

Comment: Thank u so much @Benjamin Wang

Comment: Congrats. Also, welcome to Math StackExchange.

Comment: $5^{k+1} \equiv 40k^2 -20k+5 \mod 64 \equiv 5(8k^2 -4k+1) \mod 64$, which implies that $5^k \equiv 8k^2 -4k+1 \mod 64$ which you had already derived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* $5(8n^2-4n+1)-(8(n+1)^2-4(n+1)+1)= 32 n (n - 1) \equiv 0 \bmod 64$

Answer (score 5):

Using binomial expansion,

$$5^n=(1+4)^n=1+\binom n1 4 + \binom n2 4^2 + \binom n3 \color{blue}{4^3} + \binom n4 \color{blue}{4^4} +\cdots + \binom nn \color{blue}{4^n}.$$

Since the binomial coefficients are integers and $4^3=64$, we have

$$5^n\equiv1+4n+8n(n-1)=8n^2-4n+1\bmod64.$$

Comment: Of course this isn't induction but it does show *why* it is true.

Comment: @martycohen:  I could say I used induction, to get the binomial theorem ;-)

Comment: See my answer where I generalized yours.

Comment: @martycohen That the binomial expansion still works when $\,4\to m\,$ is obvious and hardly a "generalization" worthy of another answer. In any case, this method (and question) is a dupe of many others.

Answer (score -1):

A generalization
suggested by J. W. Tanner's answer.

If $0 < j < n$ then

$\begin{array}\\
(1+m)^n
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}m^k\\
&\equiv\sum_{k=0}^j \binom{n}{k}m^k \bmod m^{j+1}\\
\text{if }
&j=2\\
(1+m)^n
&\equiv\sum_{k=0}^2 \binom{n}{k}m^k \bmod m^{3}\\
&\equiv 1+nm+\frac12n(n-1)m^2\bmod m^{3}\\
&\equiv 1+n(m-\frac12m^2)+\frac12n^2m^2\bmod m^{3}\\
\text{if}
&m=4\\
5^n
&\equiv 1-4n+8n^2 \bmod 64\\
\end{array}
$